# Cant update modalform into database and always error 404 laravel 8

Tags: php, modal-dialog, edit

I want to setup Edit Modal Form but always failed in update data, when i click update button in edit modal, it always redirect to 404 page, but the url in the browser its appropriate with route register in route file,

Is it need jquery for handle update modal form or not?

here my Controller:
RoleController.php

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Permissions;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

    public function edit(Role $role) {
        return view('admin.permissions.roles.edit', [
            'role' => $role
        ] );
    }

    public function update(Request $role, $id) {
        request()->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
        ]);
        $role = Role::findOrFail($role->id);
        $role->update([
           'name' => request('name'),
           'guard_name' => request('guard_name')?? 'web',
       ]);
       return back();
```

My route:
adminroute.php

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\Permissions\RoleController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserManageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Permissions\RoleManageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleManageController as ControllersRoleManageController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

//USER ROLE
    Route::put('user-roles/{role}/update',[RoleController::class, 'update'])->name('roles.update');
```

I was trying to change the route in form action, but it never success
and my view
admin/permissions/roles/edit.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
    @foreach($roles as $role)
    <table class="card">
        <form action="{{ route('roles.update', $role->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('patch')
            <div class="modal fade" id="editform-{{ $role->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="form"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="editrole">Edit Role</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('name') ?? $role->name }} ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="guard_name">Guard Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="guard_name" id="guard_name"
                                    placeholder='Default to "Web"' class="form-control"
                                    value="{{ old('guard_name') ?? $role->guard_name }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </table>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Route change that i tried :
Route::match
Route::resource
but always failed to update modalform, and redirect to 404 page

I was searching for literature but not solve till now, i would happy if you help my problem. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: fyi, `<form>` inside `<table>` is not allowed (`<table>` in fact doesn't have any use here since you don't use `<tr>`s).

Comment: Try changing your form action to `{{ route('roles.update', ['role' => $role]) }}`

Comment: thanks for advice, i tried to change form action to  {{ route('roles.update', ['role' => $role]) }} , but the response still the same 404